# Why is Certificate/Client secret disappearing in azure ad app during addKey/addPassword requests?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to add a client secret using [addPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) followed immediately (after a `200` response is received from addPassword) by adding a certificate using [addKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addkey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) ("type": "AsymmetricX509Cert), the new client secret disappears in the azure portal (It is visible for a few seconds). The certificate is stored permanently.
The same thing happens to the new certificate if the requests are done the other way around.
No error messages are given, I get a `200` in return from the addKey request and a `200` (and the secretText) from the addPassword request.
If I add a delay of 15 seconds between requests, both the new client secret and the new certificate are stored permanently and can be seen in the portal.
Why do the certificate and key disappear (without delay between requests)?

Comment: Hello @user12041174, this issue appears due to concurrent write calls. When two API calls write to the same object at the same time, both of them return a successful response but one call will overwrite the change made by another call. This is not the recommended approach and can be resolved by doing a read API call after write and check if the object is updated. Another approach could be making the calls with a few seconds delay.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nishant-MSFTIdentity. My description above may have been be a bit imprecise. The calls are not done at the same time. The second call is done after a 200 response is received from the first call. I can even add a delay of 2 seconds starting from receiving 200 from the first call and the second call, with the same outcome. But I agree, there seem to be some sort of overwriting issue going on.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Please add a delay of => 5seconds, that should help prevent the overwrite...if it doesn't ..another strategy can be doing a read before making the other call.  Please let us know if the issue persists.